# Insert date and get it in wrong format

Tags: java, sqlite, datetime, jdbc

I insert the current date in a table. I have a method to get the current datet:

```
private static java.sql.Date getCurrentDate() {
        java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
        return new java.sql.Date(today.getTime());
     }
```

Or in  some cases I get the date from a from in a String format e.g. `2016-10-12` and then I call this method with `action.setTodayInfo(session, getCurrentDate());` to insert to a table the date and some Boolean variables

```
public void setTodayInfo(HttpSession session, Date date) 
            throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("Initialize today's info...");

        String sq = "INSERT INTO IsSELECTED (date, morning, noon, night) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

    try {       
        Class.forName(typeDB);
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(path);            
        stm = c.prepareStatement(sq);

        PreparedStatement stm = c.prepareStatement(sq);

        stm.setDate(1, date);
        stm.setBoolean(2, FALSE);
        stm.setBoolean(3, FALSE);
        stm.setBoolean(4, FALSE);

        int rowsAffected = stm.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) { 
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
    if (stm != null) {
        stm.close();
    }
    if (c != null) {
        c.close();
    }
}          
}
```

when I look in the table the date field has this `1434473268231` and not the current day in format like 2015/06/16.. 
 The table format is:

```
CREATE TABLE "IsSELECTED"(
       "date" DATETIME PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL  DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE) ,
       "morning" BOOL NOT NULL  DEFAULT (0) ,
       "noon" BOOL NOT NULL  DEFAULT (0) ,
       "night" BOOL NOT NULL  DEFAULT (0) 
 )
```

Comment: Do you use mysql or sqlite? This are different DBMS.

Comment: What is the underlying database ? And how do you "look" in the table ?

Comment: SQLIte I use. I look directly in the table with SQLite Manager

Comment: What do you get when you `select` the values from the database again (via JDBC)?

Comment: this `1434473268231 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to worry about the format of the date when storing it. The database will simply store the date instance and you can use one of its [functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to format it on retrieval.

You could also use [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.htm) to format the date on retrieval using SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 0):

Divide 1434473268231 by 24*60*60*1000*365 and you'll get 45, which is the number of the years since the start of the epoch 1970.

This means that the value you are seeing is the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970.

That should be OK - usually date values are internally stored as milliseconds since some agreed-upon point in time.

Comment: Then use a string field.

Answer (score 0):

According to this: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html SQLLite doesn't really have a special type for DATETIME.

"Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and time functions."

Comment: At first I stored the date as string. However I can't search between dates in my database if I choose to store them as a string.

Comment: You have two options. Store as number and use the build in functions of SQLlite to convert and do queries. Or switch to a different database that actually has support for date time data types.

Comment: I don't think that the problem is in SQLite... My main problem here is that i can't insert the date as "yyyy-mm-dd"